# FFMPEG - audio crackling when merging wav files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, transcode

i'm merging two audio files into 1 with a acrossfade filter.

Here is my acrossfade filter config: `acrossfade=d=10:o=1:curve1=cbr:curve2=cbr;`

The merge is working well for .mp3 files, but when one(or both) of the inputs is wav type, it results in a intense audio crackling in the overlap time.

Thanks for any help.

I'm using fluent-ffmpeg, but the command line should be it:

ffmpeg -i file1.wav file2.wav -filter_complex "acrossfade=d=10:o=1:curve1=log:curve2=log"

The log provided by fluent-ffmpeg is: [SEE THE LOGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGTvs.png)

Here are the input files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ypzTokhGarvzkzituj6UfjAymzULCmWx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Share the output you got.

Comment: Here is the output file @Gyan: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yNFdck3RWm_fAOSbsiIES3KnW5Ndtke6/view?usp=sharing

The craclink is ocurring around 2:36

Comment: does it occur when your files share the same sample rate? Also, is your filter doing any volume equalization which might raise and clip the signal on one of them?

Comment: Yes, it's occurring even when both files have the same sample hate. I'm only applying the filter in the main question: _-filter_complex "acrossfade=d=10:o=1:curve1=log:curve2=log"_